# iOS scrollview screenshot

Tags: ios, scrollview, screenshot

```
UIImage* image = nil;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(scrollView.contentSize, YES, 0);
{
    CGPoint savedContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    CGRect savedFrame = scrollView.frame;

    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
    scrollView.frame= CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.contentSize.width,scrollView.contentSize.height);

    [scrollView.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    scrollView.contentOffset = savedContentOffset;
    scrollView.frame = savedFrame;
}
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I can not get the full image  form  scrollview , But only a half , and the half is black

Comment: pls set contentsize of scrollview. `scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(SCROLLVIEW_WIDTH, SCROLLVIEW_HEIGHT);`

Comment: where should set ?

Comment: below of the `scrollview.frame`.

Comment: No, It is still  not work , still only get the upper part, and the other part is still  black .

Comment: After you change the frame size of scrollView, it will trigger the content rendering logic, which probably need a little more time before it is ready for you to take snapshot.
Add some logs probably can help you to figure out.

Comment: No, It is not work !

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Try to add

```
drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
```

after the line

```
[scrollView.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

Comment: Sorry , I can  not know the "scrollViewSubview" means .  So can you say this again ?

Comment: is your scrollview contains subview which is same size of content size ?

Comment: NO , It is not same size of content size , The scroolview's height is one third in the middle of VC.view , And There are 3 subview in the scrollview .  I try 3 func in the link , But it still same  wrong  as up there .

Comment: @sky For me your code is working fine .  Try `scrollView drawViewHierarchyInRect` Method  instead of  renderInContext

Comment: frustrating，I  used the drawViewHierarchyInRect  method instead of renderInContext , It stil  not work , The image height is right , but only  get top part ,  the down part is still black 。 cry 。。

Comment: @sky Updated answer pls check

Comment: No，I do  not think  this is a good idea . I'm going to use the subview screenshot to splice the full image  . If the time schedule  is  ok , I will to try how to use the scrollview , and then  to tell you what this happening ?